# +entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Dogs' in this model.

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, model, entity

A little question regarding Core data models.

Here is why I'm posting : `+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Dogs' in this model.`

What I wanna do :
I wanna create an app that will read/write in core data details about animals with 2 entities `Cats` and `Dogs`.

-For that I create a window-based project with "use core data" checked.
-Then I create my views, and click on "animals.xcdatamodeld" file to create a first entity called `Cats`. I add the attributes, generate the class "cats.h" and "cats.m".
- I write down the code to read and write on this entity => No problem everything works well.

- At this point I made a mistake by deleting the file "animals.xcdatamodeld" manually... I recreate it with the same name and add a new entity `Dogs` with its attributes and generate the associated class.
- That's where the problem is, when I build and run the error message comes : `+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Dogs' in this model.` FYI, the read/write on `Cats` is still ok.

I have no idea why this error appears... I did not change anything on the App Delegate. I found very little information online related to that issue.
This only thing I found was that maybe the model needs to be versioned when updated => Can someone explain that a lil bit please ?
Anyway the model does not seem to have been updated when I added the new entity...

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Ok as expected somehow, this error was due to a stupid mistake...
The deleted xcdatamodeld file was replaced by a new one with a different spelling...

Now everything's fine...

Comment: Mark this as answered by hitting the checkmark so the question shows as answered.