# OSX CoreData: issue only for some entities: +entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'myEntity' in this model

Tags: macos, core-data, swift

I've been trying to figure this one out for days :(

given:

```
println("\(context)")
if context == nil {
    println("context is nil")
}

let boardEntity: NSManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Board", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

let cardQueueEntity: NSManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("CardQueue", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
```

boardEntity saves fine. I've even verified this in the sql file directly.

cardQueueEntity produces the following error:

`+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'CardQueue' in this model.`

- println("(context)") shows `<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6080001dfd10>`
- I've tripled checked that the names match the model
  [image: Tello.xcdatamodelId]
- setting breakpoints reveals that the crash happens at the `cardQueueEntity` declaration
- I've looked into the sql file to verify that the entity names are the same there too
- I've manually removed my sqllite files (in /library/containers/..) to force a db rebuild, but the result is the same
- I've referenced [+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Dogs' in this model.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785687/entityforname-could-not-locate-an-entity-named-dogs-in-this-model) and others but couldn't find a solution
- if I comment out boards or change the ordering, boards still works and cardQueue doesn't.
- `println("\(context.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel.entitiesByName)")` shows all entities.

here's the core data stack i'm using (based on http://www.cimgf.com/2014/06/08/the-core-data-stack-in-swift),

```
@lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Tello", withExtension: "momd")
    let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)

    let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)

    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let storeURL = (urls[urls.endIndex-1]).URLByAppendingPathComponent("Tello.sqlite")

    var error: NSError? = nil

    var store = psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil, error: &error)
    if (store == nil) {
        println("Failed to load store")
    }

    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

but I get the same issue with the default Apple stack as well.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not help you if you're having the same issue, but what resolved it for me was upgrading my mac to the Yosemite beta and from XCode beta1 to beta3.

I can't say which of those two things did it - XCode makes the most sense, so try that first.

(On Mavericks editing the deployment target to explicitly build for 10.9 didn't fix the problem for me.)